# Коллекции. Добавление элемента

Tags: java, коллекции

Доброго времени суток. Новичок в Java, прохожу коллекции и возник вопрос. Если мы создали например

```
List <Data> list = new LinkedList <Data>();

public class Data{
private static String name;
private static String age;
}
```

Есть поля

```
String worker;
String exp="15";
```

Как добавлять эти элементы в этот список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш список определен как содержащий элементы типа Data, поэтому в него нельзя поместить String. Я думаю, что у вас не совсем корректный класс Data. Он содержит только статические поля и не имеет методов присвоения им значений. Вероятно он должен был быть таким:

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private String age;

    Data(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Для добавления элементов в список сначала нужно создать экземпляр класса Data, затем добавить его в список.

```
Data d = new Data("Worker", "15");
list.add(d);
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще `list.add(new Data())`.

Но у вас класс странный.

```
private static String name;
private static String age;
```

Поля всех экземпляров этого класса будут иметь одно и то же значение, так как помечены как `static`.

Comment: Если у нас есть поля которые нужно добавить в List, как тогда добавлять?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю вопрос. Попробуйте в изначальном вопросе расписать, чего вы именно хотите.